# Cannot disable systemd service

Tags: linux, dbus, centos7, systemd

I've been using the dbus API from systemd and I've been enabling services with the EnableUnitFiles() function as detailed here http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/

However, when I try to disable the same service with the command

```
systemctl disable "service_name"
```

and follow-up with a check to see if the service is disabled with

```
systemctl status "service_name"
```

it still reveals the service to be enabled. I am currently running Centos7.

Any insight would be appreciated as to why I cannot disable the service.
Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the systemd `mask` command rather than `disable`:

```
systemctl mask <service_name>
```

The `disable` command still allows the service to be started, for example, in response to another service requesting it as a dependency (even if optional), or manually. However `mask` disables the service completely.

Also, I don't believe either `mask` or `disable` actually stop a running service: they just configure the startup of that service in the future. Therefore, you should also do `systemctl stop <service_name>`.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Although I was wondering why after I perform `systemctl disable "service_name"` and with a check using `systemctl status "service_name"` it still shows in the "Loaded:" field that it is enabled? Is there anyway to change this status to disabled as opposed to what mask does which is change it to /dev/null. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. In my opinion this is poor design, `disable` should do what `mask` does and peprhaps have another option such as `soft-disable` doing with `disable` currently does.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod -x <service exec>
```

or rename it

I just disabled the OpenVPN server like that. systemctl disable or systemctl mask didn't work. After a reboot, the service was still there (Ubuntu Server 22.04).

I know it is HIGHLY NOT an elegant solution, but it is the only one that works for sure.